# Debugging huge trees in c

Tags: c

I have a C application that manages huge trees, as in barely fits into memory. The application currently has no graphical user interface. I want to debug those trees, e.g. traverse them in some way. I need some textual information per node, say 20 characters. The trees in memory do not contain that extra debug information, so it would need to be generated while traversing. I don't need any fancy browsing/searching, just the general way one handles hierarchical data.

I was wondering how I could do that with the **least effort**:

- Dump the data into a file in *some format* and Display it with *some program* that can handle so much data.

  - Along that lines I was thinking of just abusing the file system by creating a directory structure, but that would not scale
- Use a GUI library for C (GTK?)

  - needs to support lazy evaluating
  - If it would be beneficial, I could also use a C++ GUI Library

It's really about least effort, It's just for debugging, not about a long lasting solution.
I am not really limited to a specific system or libraries (Can be Linux or Windows).

Comment: Please provide some more specific measurements on just how large these trees are. If the pared-down tree barely fits in memory, a larger tree with enough data to make the visualization useful sounds even harder to fit. On the other hand, you could create the visualization on a different machine, perhaps.

Comment: What is it that you need to do?  What problems are you trying to solve by inspecting these trees?  That would affect how you go about traversing them (for example, problems in the STRUCTURE of the tree would be handled differently than ones in the CONTENT).

Comment: @unwind, an annotated tree with the necessary debug information would likely not fit into memory. Therefore I could either dump this into a file or It could to be generated on the fly during the browsing of the tree (obviously the tree would never be displayed in full at one time)

Comment: @Scott Hunter: I need content, but the content fits into labels of the nodes, say 20 chars. Browsing, like you would browse a directory tree (without looking at contents of files) is sufficient.

Comment: Another possible solution might be to buy some more RAM, which is cheap these days

Answer (score 2):

Dumping the data seems to be best. You can try packages such as [`graphviz`](http://www.graphviz.org/), [`gnuplot`](http://www.gnuplot.info/), and [xy-pic](http://www.tug.org/applications/Xy-pic/) to make your graphs.

Otherwise, you might find [`ddd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) helpful, it can visualize graphs. But it might not be a good fit if you're low on memory.

Comment: 1) I fear that a static image would be WAY too large to handle. Does any of those packages allow dynamic browsing?
2) Yes I thought about debuggers, but then I would miss the extra information that I need to compute on the fly.

Comment: @Zulan: 1) GraphViz does, and so does ddd. 2) What extra information? And why couldn't you compute it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of an approach that requires very little additional memory (because it does not rebuild the entire tree), does support browsing the tree, and seems like it could be put together quickly (disclaimer: I haven't tried yet):

Write, in your favorite scripting language, a CGI program that takes as its input a list of addresses (or just the symbol corresponding to the top of your tree structure).  The script then begins a gdb process and attaches it to the process containing your tree.  Using the list of addresses provided, it walks the tree, building an html representation as it goes, using gdb to call your describe_this_node() function at each stop.  At each node, include a link which calls the same CGI program again, providing the path to that node as input.  In the bottom-most displayed node, provide links for the child nodes.

I realize this approach may just replicate functionality found in graphical debuggers such as ddd, but the intent is to provide a minimalist approach that requires very little extra memory.